# How to Run for an hour in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried several times to code that will display text for an hour, after the functions has occurred.

But the function *Date* exist on a time period of day, hour, minute, I just want to display the text for one hour.

```
    Fucntion() {
       var Text = "Show for an hour and will disappear after an hour.";
    }
```

**EDIT (1):**

To put it simply
if the user click on function called get contents in json for an hour, it appears on the site for all users, on each click of the function the data from json is called and displayed for an hour.

```
funtion click() {

var url = "https://example.com";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

xhr.send();

var Text = xhr.responseText;
setTimeout(Text, 1000);

}
```

Comment: have you looked into `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Why do you add the ajax tag? If you have to implement just a function using vanilla js, use setTimeout() as @mykaf mentioned.

Comment: Answer really depends on other factors. Like it is just that page load / browser session, is it just for a user, all users, etc.

Comment: @Alexey Zalyotov im I edited, please see EDIT (1)

Comment: @mykaf This is only visible to one user, and I want to show the content to all users.

Comment: @epascarello all users :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a certain displayed text element to disappear after 60 minutes you should start a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 60*60*1000=3600000 milliseconds.

In order to be able to demonstrate the effect I shortened the time delay here to 10 seconds = 10000 ms:

```js
setTimeout(_=>document.querySelector("h2").style.display="none",10000);
```

```html
<h2>This will disappear after 10 seconds</h2>
```

In order to query a server in two second intervals and show the result on every's website you could do this:

```js
const h2=document.querySelector("h2"),
  url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";
let i=0;

setInterval(_=>
 fetch(url+(i=i%10+1)).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>h2.textContent=i+' '+d.name)
,2000);
```

```html
<h2></h2>
```

Comment: I edited, please see EDIT (1)

Comment: If you want things to (dis-)appear in the same way to all users visiting your site, you will need some kind of serverside script that is capable of receiving and processing the "start signal" for starting the "grace period". Once this signal was received, a deadline for showing the text is set and after that time the repeatedly requesting browsers of all page visitors will stop displaying the text.

Comment: Can you write a code that requests to get every 5 seconds, or asks continuously, if it gets data, the text is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the same countdown for all the users, you definitely should use not only a frontend but a backend as well:

1. Create an object on the backend which will be responsible for the active countdown and contain needed info (start_time, end_time, name, etc.)
2. Create before/after action callback in your root controller: each request from the frontend to the backend (aka load a new page/reload the current page) will check if any active countdown is present; if yes - set the `countdown` cookies with the end date
3. In the frontend render component if the `countdown` cookies are present, parse the end date and render the countdown.

Comment: Nice, is there an example for that?  I want to display data from json via an external link.  Displays to all users.

Comment: `to display data from json via an external link` - what does it mean, @i0x4r? Which part of the suggested solution do you want me to provide with a code example?